# use grep command to get a word after a match [ Linux ]

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I've this command `grep -oP '.*?(?=\:)'` which gets words before : character, the thing I want is to get all the words after : character
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\K`, which tells the engine to pretend that the match attempt started at this position. You can have something like:

```sh
grep -oP '.*:\K(.*)'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "hello:world" | grep -oP ":\K.*"
world
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get a *word* after the *last* `:`, you need

```sh
grep -oP '.*:\K\w+' file
```

If you need to get a word after the *first* `:`, you need

```sh
grep -oP '^[^:]*:\K\w+'
```

If you need to get all the words after a `:`, you need

```sh
grep -oP ':\K\w+'
```

If a "word" is a sequence of non-whitespace chars, you need to replace `\w` with `\S`:

```sh
grep -oP '.*:\K\S+' file
grep -oP '^[^:]*:\K\S+'
```

If a "word" is a sequence of any Unicode letters, you need to replace `\w` with `\p{L}`:

```sh
grep -oP '.*:\K\p{L}+' file
grep -oP '^[^:]*:\K\p{L}+'
```

**NOTES**:

- `\K` is a *match reset operator* that clears out the current overall match memory buffer.
- `-o` - option that outputs the matched substrings, not matched lines
- `-P` - enables the PCRE regex engine rather than the default POSIX one.